# Blank "Repositories View" with new Eclipse RCP 4.16 and Egit 5.8

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, egit, eclipse-2020-06

I have a problem when updating from egit 5.4 to 5.8 and also updating to latest Eclipse RCP 4.16 .
The clone operation works ok, but the "Repositories view" remains empty. The Added repos can be selected from the GitStaging view. No errors in the logs, how can I solve that?

[image: empty repository view after repo is added]

[The AddRepositories view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oli7V.png)  This is how the addRepositories view look, I tried with brand new repos and also with existing ones. still they arent'd displayed in the Git Repositories view

Comment: Click the second (the first yellow) toolbar button to add exisiting Git repositories to this view.

Comment: @howlger Well that's actually the problem...Obviously i selected a repository before and still the Repositories view remains empty. But in the Git Staging view i have the option of switching between repository, and the repository added previously is there.

Comment: Is your Git repository or your workspace on a network drive? Which operating system?

Comment: no, i tried with local git repository/ workspace and it still doesn't work. Using Windows10

Comment: It works for me using Windows 10. Could you please show your _Add Git Repositories_ dialog and tell what you did there? Please also tell the location of your workspace and the location of the Git repositories you added. Can you reproduce this issue using a new workspace?

Comment: @howlger My workspace is on Desktop and the repos are at C:\something\Repo..I get this error for a new workspace also

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this is overriding the following method in the ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor class:

```
  @Override
  public IAdaptable getDefaultPageInput() {
     return ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
  }
```

Comment: Thanx a lot, this solves the problem in our eclipse RCP application